# Android NFC P2P when NdefMessage was sent?

Tags: android, nfc, nfc-p2p

I made an application NFC P2P send `Ndef` data between 2 Smart Phones.
When I send a `MDEF` message to other phone, I use `enableForegroundNdefPush()` method.
But, how to known when the `Mdef` message was sent?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the Android NDEF push mechanism does not support any kind of notification when a P2P transaction has finished.

Comment: looks like IceCream Sandwich has added a callback for this now.